# Add [bit-fiddling] as a synonym to [bit-manipulation]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

I've checked the [bit-fiddling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bit-fiddling) tag. It has only 16 questions, all of which are about bitwise operations, and no one is watching it. It has a wiki excerpt:

> Doing operations on individual bits or pieces of data shorter than a word, usually in name of efficiency and with a cost in clarity. The main tools are bitwise operations (and, or, etc.), shifts and rotations, and bit masking.

which is also about bit manipulation [bit-manipulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bit-manipulation):

> The manipulation of individual bits. Operators used may include bitwise AND, OR, XOR, NOT, left-shift, and right-shift.

I suggests adding it as a synonym to [bit-manipulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bit-manipulation).

Or should we retag those questions and remove the tag?

I'm not sure about the *native* usage but Google considers "bit fiddling" and "bit twiddling" synonyms of "bit manipulation" when you search for either of them. Below are some example I found

- Jeu George's [Bit Fiddling series](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jeuge/2005/) on MSDN
- [GNU MP 6.1.2: Integer Logic and Bit Fiddling](https://gmplib.org/manual/Integer-Logic-and-Bit-Fiddling.html)
- [When does bit-fiddling come to Kotlin?](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/when-does-bit-fiddling-come-to-kotlin/2249)
- [UNIX C Programming - Chapter 15: Bit Fiddling](http://stevevincent.info/216_15.htm)
- [C Primer Plus, Fifth Edition by Stephen Prata - CHAPTER 15 - BIT FIDDLING](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/c-primer-plus/0672326965/ch15.html)
- [Santa Monica College CS 101 hw8 - CS 539 Programming in C Homework Bit-Fiddling](https://www.coursehero.com/file/18426011/hw8/)
- [Tips and Tricks for ECL -- Part 1 -- Bit Fiddling](https://hpccsystems.com/blog/tips-and-tricks-ecl-part-1-bit-fiddling)

Comment: As for the retag part, don't go to do it. It's just one button for me which can create a synonym. There's no need to do heavy work :)  .... Ping me once there's clear consensus and that there's no one who opposes this. (give it a day or so)

Comment: Makes sense. Bit Twiddling is already a synonym.

Comment: I've never heard of Bit Fiddling, though I have heard of Bit Twiddling, is this native usage?

Comment: @opa I've seen bit fiddling a lot more than bit twiddling, which only appears on the bit hacks page that I've always just remembered the Bit Hacks part

Comment: @opa - I'm with you. This is the first time I have ever heard of bit *fiddling* but I have always known this as bit *twiddling* (going back 25 or 30 years for me personally). [Wikipedia's bit manipulation entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_manipulation) explicitly mentions twiddling (and bashing), but not fiddling. And of course it was mentioned that twiddling is already a synonym here on SO.